# SQL Query logic to count re-assigned records

Tags: sql

I have the following table in which mechanics are assigned to Vehicles.  I am trying to figure out how to sum all of the assignments and subtract all re-assignments for each mechanic.

The results should be the mechanic N0055345 should have 2 assignments and mechanic N0057581 should have 0 (due to re-assignement).

```
Auto ID EntryDate       Mechanic ID      Vehicle Type
1022013 8/17/2013       N0055345          CAR
1022011 8/15/2013       N0057581          CAR
1022011 8/19/2013       N0055345          CAR
```

Thanks,
Brad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The results should be the mechanic N0055345 should have 2 assignments
>   and mechanic N0057581 should have 0 (due to re-assignement).

There is no indication in your data of how to get to this. If this is the data set you want, then you aren't looking for the latest assignment of a mechanic, you want the total of all their current assignments. As said, nothing in your data shows what a reassignment is.

If there is currently not a way of doing this, and you aren't removing the record in assignments when reassigned, I'd suggest adding a "CurrentlyAssigned" flag to the table, then you can filter on that. When they're reassigned, switch the flag.

Table Data (Assignments)

```
AutoID  EntryDate   MechanicID  VehicleType  CurrentlyAssigned
1022011 8/19/2013   N0055345    CAR          1
1022011 8/18/2013   N0057581    CAR          0
1022014 8/15/2013   N0055345    CAR          1
```

Query

```
SELECT MechanicID, COUNT(*) as [NumberOfAssignments]
FROM Assignments
WHERE CurrentlyAssigned = 1
GROUP BY MechanicID
```

Output

```
MechanicId    NumberOfAssignments
N0055345      2
```

If you want to include those with no assignments, the benefit of using a 0/1 flag means you can sum it.

Query

```
SELECT MechanicID, SUM(CONVERT(INT,CurrentlyAssigned)) as [NumberOfAssignments]
FROM Assignments
GROUP BY MechanicID
```

Output

```
MechanicId    NumberOfAssignments
N0055345      2
N0057581      0
```

Answer (score 0):

So the theory I'm going with here is that I only want to count mechanics as assigned on the "latest" record per `auto_id`.

```
SELECT mechanic
     , Count(*)
FROM   (
        SELECT mechanic
             , Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY auto_id ORDER BY entry_date DESC) As row_num
        FROM   your_table 
       ) As x
WHERE  row_num = 1
GROUP
    BY mechanic
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the *current* assignment for the mechanics.  So, you need to select the most recent record for each auto.  If your database supports window functions, you can readily find the maximum and do the comparison in the `sum()` statement:

```
SELECT mechanic, sum(case when entrydate = maxdate then 1 else 0 end)
FROM (SELECT mechanic, max(entrydate) OVER (PARTITION BY autoid) as maxdate
      FROM t
     ) t
GROUP BY mechanic;
```

It is important not to filter the data, otherwise you will lost the mechanics that have 0 cars.